# Why was the Original Koryo form replaced?

Tags: tae-kwon-do, forms

Most people know of Koryo, the first Black Belt form in Kukkiwon/WTF Taekwondo. However, few people today know that there once was a different version of Koryo practiced before by the KTA. This original version of Koryo was replaced by the newer version in 1972. There is not much information around regarding the reason for the change. Why was the original Koryo replaced with the newer version practiced today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, it was [a matter of politics](http://jungdokwan-taekwondo.blogspot.com/2014/08/palgwe-forms-original-koryo-as-bonus.html) when the schools were joined.

> Why did we replace Palgwe with Taegeuk? This was a political motivated move. In 1965-67 all the schools together made Palgwe forms so they could all practise [sic] one common set of forms. At this time the Ji Do Kwan and Moo Duk Kwan which were very big and succsefull [sic] were not part of the Korean Taekwondo Association. Later these two schools also joined the organisation and to keep the spirit of all the schools contributing to the forms in that organisation they made the Taegeuk forms and a new Koryo Poomsae with representatives from all the schools including Ji Do Kwan and Moo Duk Kwan. Another reason that is often stated is that the Palgwe forms looked too much like "Karate Kata" while the Taegeuk forms were made to make them look less like Karate forms.